# How to execute mongodb find query in a loop in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I am trying to execute mongodb find query in a loop. 
I have an object with some properties. The value of each property will be checked in the mongodb to get its 
updated value. Once all the property values are updated, i want to perform some other actions.

But before getting the updated object(updatedVehObj), the next line of code (function updatedVehicleData ) 
is getting executed and its throwing some error,since i dont have the updated values.

Thanks in advance for any help to solve this issue or any better methods for achieving this result.

```
const processVehData = async (vehData) => {
  const vehObj = {
    make: 'AUD',
    model: 'A12',
    type: 'S',
  }
  const updatedVehObj = await getDBMapping(vehObj)
  // Do some preocessing with the updated vehicle obj
  const processedDataRes = updatedVehicleData(updatedVehObj)
  return processedDataRe;
}

const getDBMapping = async (vehObj) => {
  let updatedVeh = {}
  MongoClient.connect(connectionStr, mongoOptions, async (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error in connecting to DB')
    }
    const dbo = client.db('VehicleDataBase')
    for (const key of Object.keys(vehObj)) {
      // Iterating every element in the object
      await dbo
        .collection(key)  // key name will be the collection name in mongodb
        .find({         
          code: vehObj[key],
        })
        .toArray()
        .then(result => {
          updatedVeh[key] = result[0] // Framing new object with updated values
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(' Error in getting mapping', err)
        })
    }
    return updatedVeh;
    /*** Expected result
      updatedVeh = {
        "make": "AUDI",
        "model" : "A3 Auto",
        "type" : "Sedan"
      }
    ****/
  })
}

const updatedVehicleData = vehData => {
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem came from the `callback` of `MongoClient.connect()`, when performing `await getDBMapping(vehObj)` you are not waiting for something to be resolved.

Also, you combined `await` and `then` on update queries.

A solution could be to use a `Promise` in `getDBMapping` function :

```js
const getDBMapping = async (vehObj) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let updatedVeh = {}
  MongoClient.connect(connectionStr, mongoOptions, async (err, client) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error in connecting to DB')
      return reject(err); // reject is there is an error
    }

    const dbo = client.db('VehicleDataBase')
    for (const key of Object.keys(vehObj)) {
      // use try / catch instead of combined await / then
      try {
        const result = await dbo
          .collection(key)
          .find({         
            code: vehObj[key],
          })
          .toArray();

        updatedVeh[key] = result[0];
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error in getting mapping', err)
        // reject(err); => you can also reject here, but it could break batch update transaction
      }
    }

    return resolve(updatedVeh);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your problem *"But before getting the updated object(updatedVehObj), the next line of code (function updatedVehicleData ) is getting executed and its throwing some error,since i dont have the updated values."*

You have to write same async and await before this function,

```
const processedDataRes = await updatedVehicleData(updatedVehObj)

const updatedVehicleData = async vehData => {
  // Do something
}
```